# I always get the Getting HTTP-404 error in the Spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop my first spring mvc application and get the above error.
I search dozen of solution of same exception but can not find any solution.

here is my web.xml

```
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="m"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />


   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/</value>

   </property>
   <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
   </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Hello.ds">
NAME : <input type="text" name="hello">
 <input type="submit" value="OK"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class jnk  {
@RequestMapping("/Hello")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest r,HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception{

        String name=r.getParameter("name");
        ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("success");
        m.addObject("MSG", name);
        return m;
    }

}
```

My jsp files are reside under WEB-INF/ 
directory

the package name is : m

Comment: I notice you are using JSPs. You may want to review this sample project from Spring Boot, which illustrates a basic JSP configuration. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main

Answer (score 1):

The controller exposes a mapping named `/Hello` (see: `@RequestMapping("/Hello")`) but your form is attempting to submit to `/Hello.ds` (see `<form action="/Hello.ds">`).

Comment: I chamge  @RequestMapping("/Hello") to  @RequestMapping("/Hello.ds ") but it still not work and give the error    HTTP Status 404 - /Hello.ds   description The requested resource is not available.